# Error al instalar Yarn

Tags: javascript, nodejs, visual-studio, cmd, yarn

Necesito ayuda para recuperar el fichero './yarn-lock.js' ya que lo eliminé por error. Al ejecutar cualquier código 'npm install ..' me salta el error:

[image: Previamente he introducido npm install --global yarn]

He probado a descargar el archivo manualmente, reinstalar node.js, etc. pero nada. ¿Algún consejo?

Comment: ¿Utilizas yarn o utilizas npm? Ten en cuenta que son dos gestores diferentes. En todo caso intenta usar `yarn install`. El archivo `*-lock.json` usualmente suele ser autogenerado por el comando `install`.

Comment: Buenas! Ya probé de todo. Utilizo npm, pero a través de este quería instalar yarn. El error me lo da npm, ya que no puedo instalar yarn ni por lo tanto "yarn install"

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta para dejar más en claro lo que intentas hacer? Es decir, quieres instalar yarn a través de npm usando `npm i yarn` y ¿es cuando obtienes este error? Adicionalmente, ¿has intentado ver si el archivo .log contiene más indicios del posible problema?